# How do you delete a custom object with a Lightning record page from Managed package?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, managed-package, lightning-apps, record

I believe we can delete custom objects in a managed package once all dependencies are removed.
Unfortunately we have a Lightning record page created for one of these custom objects.

It seems we [cannot delete Lightning pages from a released managed package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm#packaging_packageable_components).

I have removed all the components,etc. in the Lightning page just to make sure there is no dependent field, etc. It still doesn't allow me to delete it.

Is there a way to remove the Lightning page link to custom object and help me to delete the custom object eventually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Salesforce Partner Support,

> It's not possible to delete the custom object until it's convert the
>   beta version. To convert this in Beta version, You need to follow the
>   below prerequisite.
>
> The requirements are as follows:
>
> - the package is not installed in any organization
> - subsequent versions are also not installed in any organization
> - there is no patch org created for the specific package version
>
> Then, Our tier-3 can convert this in the beta version.

Unfortunately we're not able to go down this path, and decided to leave it with label prefix "Obsolete".

Comment: Sounds like what they are asking is to create a new version that nobody has installed, and proceed with that.

Comment: Hi @CharlesT I think they want us to revert managed package to the version of which we added the custom object, so they can convert it to beta, and then we can delete the object/component from the beta version.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to engage support for assistance. This is outlined in the [help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-do-I-remove-components-from-a-Managed-Package-1327108663841&language=en_US&type=1).

> Support can change the release version from Managed-Released, to Managed-Beta if certain conditions are met. Be sure to provide support with the following details:
>
> i. Package Version details -  Name, version, etc.
>
> ii. Package version in question and later versions should not be currently installed in any subscriber org (if installed, they need to be uninstalled)
>
> iii. If the package version in question and later versions have patch org created. If you do have any patch org created, please mention that in your case and confirm if it is ok to purge the patch org. (Patch org needs to be purged to revert the package)

Also, be sure to read the warnings:

> The package will need to go through security review again, once changes are made and new version is released.
>
> Review fee will also apply, please work with your PAM / TE for more details on the fee.
>
> All subsequent released versions will also be reverted to beta, eg, if v1.2 is requested to be reverted to beta and v1.3 & 1.4 were released, all released versions after v1.2 will also be reverted.

So, if you meet the conditions above, and you're willing to accept the consequences, Support can fix your problem. It's better to fix it as soon as possible if you can, preferably before (ii) above becomes a problem (e.g. before subscribers start upgrading to it).

Answer (score 0):

In the packaging org, is the Flexipage set as the "org-wide default" for the custom object? That would get stored on the object metadata as a dependency. If you can remove that it should help.

Comment: Thanks @Charles T, this is already done. There is some link somewhere which we cannot find to delete, I believe if we can find the link, we can remove, and then delete the object. Waiting on Salesforce support on this. cheers!